# Need help referencing a previous daily candle

Tags: tradingview-api

I need some help.

I currently have a code that gives me a buy or sell signal with regards to daily timeframe criteria that I have set.

I have also coded intraday to give me the relevant signals.  But what i would like is to get intraday to show me the signals that match the previous daily candle.  For example; If yesterdays daily candle showed me a buy, then today I would like intraday timeframes to only show me buys and to remove the sells.  And of course vice versa, if the previous daily showed me a sell signal, then todays intraday price should show me sells only on the following day.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

some examples
close[1] is the previous close. similarly high[1] is the previous high. If you are on a day chart it will take the previous day's close or high value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).